# VM101:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, django, fetch, e-commerce

I am using Sandbox for payment testing. Everything works fine till payment and the console throws an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

The error points to:

```
fetch(url, {
```

. I am not sure what's wrong with the Django app. I even have initialized URL at the top:

```
var url = "{% url 'payments' %}"


 onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                console.log(details);
                sendData();
                function sendData(){
                    fetch(url, {
                        method : "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-type": "application/json",
                            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            orderID: orderID,
                            transID: details.id,
                            payment_method: payment_method,
                            status: details.status,
                        }),
                    })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        window.location.href = redirect_url + '?order_number='+data.order_number+'&payment_id='+data.transID;
                    })
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: `this line of code` which line? this one `.then((response) => response.json())` ... your server isn't sending valid JSON, it's probably sending HTML

Answer (score 0):

Either there is an internal server error, or you the server is not sending a Json response. You can check the status by using `.then((response)=>console.log(response.status)` to check if there is an internal server error, if the console.log shows 500 error code, then it is server error. else the server is not sending proper json response.

Comment: I tried, and it says 500 (Internal Server Error). I am not sure what's causing the error.

Comment: ok, now it seems to be an issue with the django backend so can you share the views and url that you are serving to the frontend

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not returning json from the server, try doing `res.text()` instead of `res.json()`, and see if that fixes it, if it does, you are not returning proper json from your server.